# Discord.js ~ message.delete()

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have an error with my code:

```js
async (client, message, args) => {
  if (!message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) {
    message.delete({ timeout: 10000 });
    message.channel
      .send(
        `**${message.author.username}**, you need the \`ADMINISTRATOR\` permission to use this command.`
      )
      .then((msg) => {
        msg.delete({ timeout: 10000 });
      });
  }
};
```

The error:

```js
(node:2095) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
```

Can you help me to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: This means `message.channel` is undefined. Where are you running your command?

Comment: On a channel. Not in DM..

Comment: Is `message.delete` working?

Comment: Yes it works, finaly, i decided remove message.delete(). Well, I think this error was in another command I think, cuz its impossible to have this error with my correct code. Anyways, thanks for the help!

Comment: The argument to message.channel.send() seems to be using back quotes.  Shouldn't it be single or double quotes?